# ModelState: Validate only the properties that are inside the form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, modelstate

I have a `User` class with multiple string properties, all of them required. The properties are used for different actions, like Create and Update.

In my form, on create action, i am using only a part of these properties, and, because of this, the `ModelState` is invalid.

Is there a way to specify to the `ModelState` that it should validate only the properties that are included in the POST data (inside the form) ? So the missing properties are ignored?

Answer (score 1):

You can create different models for user creation and other actions with different sets of validation attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you should create different view models for each specific action method ( if they have specific requirements ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `RequiredIf` attribute from [Foolproof](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/) to achieve this:

```
using Foolproof;

[RequiredIf("Tab", "Information")]
public bool UW_AgentCreditReportsAknowlegement { get; set; }
```

Just use one of the attributes and set the appropriate condition.